# USA Coding Olympiad 1st Timed Out and/or Too Much Memory

Tags: java

A few days ago, I participated in the USA coding olympiad for the first time, and got the same error on all my codes. I can't figure out why because it told me that I did incredibly well on the first test case, so I don't understand how the other 9 all timed out. Could someone please explain what is wrong with my code.
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5eaa.png)
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y5UC.png)

```
import java.io.*;
public class milkmeasure {
    private static int [] cows ={7,7,7};
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // initialize file I/O
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("measurement.in"));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("measurement.out")));
        int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String [] entries = new String [N];
        for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
            entries [i]= br.readLine();
        }
        int topCow = 1;
        int finalN = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
            String lowEntry = entries[lownum(N,entries)];
            String name = lowEntry.substring(2,lowEntry.substring(2).indexOf(" ")+2);
            int effect = Integer.parseInt(lowEntry.substring(lowEntry.substring(2).indexOf(" ")+3));
            if (name.equals("Bessie")){cows[1]+=effect;}
            else if (name.equals("Elsie")){cows[2]+=effect;}
            else if (name.equals("Mildred")){cows[0]+=effect;}
            int newTop = findTop();
            if (newTop!=topCow){finalN++;}
            topCow = newTop;
            entries[lownum(N,entries)]="101 ";
        }
        pw.println(finalN);
        pw.close();
    }

    private static int lownum (int N, String [] entries){
        int lowNum = 101;
        int returnInt=0;
        for (int i =0; i<N; i++){
            int a = Integer.parseInt(entries[i].substring(0,entries[i].indexOf(" ")));
            if (a<lowNum){
                lowNum = a;
                returnInt =i;
            }
        }
        return returnInt;
    }

    private static int findTop (){
        int maxval = 0;
        int returnval =0;
        for (int i =0; i<3; i++){
            if (cows[i]>= maxval){
                returnval += cows[i]*cows[i];
                maxval=cows[i];
            }
        }
        return returnval;
    }
}
```

Comment: We have no idea what the code is supposed to do so we probably cannot suggest a different approach.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained.  For this question, that means at least providing the relevant bounds on the program input.  It would be helpful to explain what the program is supposed to do, too, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: So what input did this fail for?  And what are the memory and/or time constraints that failed?  And most importantly of all, what is it actually supposed to do?  I believe this question is unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: The constraints were 4 seconds and 256 megabytes of data. My question wasn't really about the correctness of the code in terms of the problem, but why it didn't meet these constraints.

Comment: I posted what the program should do in the picture called "problem." Sorry for not including it in original post.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Avoid  links to external screen shots or images.

Comment: Results say "Runtime error or memory limit exceeded". Were there any limitation on input stated in the task? What if delta or cumulative result for a particular cow exceeds `int`?

Comment: as i said a few comments up, it had to be less than 4 seconds and less than 256 gigabytes. Sorry that wasn't in original post @Ivan

Comment: No idea.  I can't see what would make this program take more than 4 seconds (and do you really mean 256 gigabytes?).  But `findTop` seems odd to me.  It doesn't seem to be returning a cow number, but you're using it as if it did.  This could be the source of an error, but not the one you described.

Comment: Thanks Dawood! findtop returns a value that will be unique to any configuration of top cows, and this is all I need to find if that has changed. I did mean MB, though.

Answer (score 0):

### Algorithmic complexity issue

For each entry, your `main()` method invokes `lownum()` (twice).  `lownum()` scans all the entries to identify and return the one with the lowest day number.  Overall, then, the complexity of your program scales at least as o(N<sup>2</sup>) in the number of entries.

That lower bound could be reduced to o(N log N) by sorting the entries once and then simply processing them in order.

With a reasonable bound on the maximum day number of the entries, and the given assurance that there is at most one entry per day, it could be reduced further to o(N) by assigning entries to an array or List at positions corresponding to their day numbers, so that no actual sorting is required.

It turns out that this is the main driver of your asymptotic complexity, so improving this lower bound allows you to improve the upper bound, too, all the way to O(N).

### General efficiency issues

Since the problem specifies that there will be at most one entry per day for 100 days, however, you are probably in a regime that is still strongly influenced by (in-)efficiencies that affect the cost coefficient.  And you in fact have quite a few inefficiencies.  Among them:

- You parse each entry many times, scanning to split them into fields and converting some of those into integers.  That's terribly wasteful.  It would be far more efficient to parse each entry just once, and then store the parsed results.  In fact, you can get the parsing at input for almost free by using a `Scanner`.
- You invoke the `lownum()` method twice for each entry.  The current implementation of this method is expensive, as discussed above, and nothing changes between the first and second invocation that would affect the result.
- (minor) you perform full string comparisons on the cow names, even though it would be sufficient to look only at their first letters
- (minor) you invoke separate methods to find the next entry and to compute the new top cow.  Method invocation is comparatively expensive, so it is a bit inefficient to make large numbers of invocations of methods that do very little work.  That's probably not a significant effect for your particular code, however.